# Should I make only one `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` at a time in ServerSocket/Socket?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

Let say I have a `Server` and `Client` with the following task:

> - Authenticate (Sending and Receiving authentication code)
> - Continue Receiving Message
> - Continue sending Heartbeat message

and I coded it like:

```
public class Sample{

    /** Some code here... **/

    //Everything start in authentication() method.
    private void authenticate(){
        //...
        List<Object> msg = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        msg.add(0, AUTHENTICATION);
        msg.add(1, id);
        output.writeObject(msg);
        output.flush();
        output.reset();

        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        msg.addAll((Collection<?>) input.readObject());
        input.reset();

        /** Validate **/
        if(AUTHENTICATION_IS_TRUE){
            startSendingHeartBeat();
            startReceivingMessage();
        }
    }

    private void startSendingHeartBeat(){
        //...
        List<Object> msg = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        while(true){
            msg.clear();
            msg.add(0, "XXX");
            msg.add(1, id);
            output.writeObject(msg);
            output.flush();
            output.reset();
        }
    }

    private void startReceivingMessage(){
        //...
        List<Object> msg = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while(true){
           msg.clear();
           msg.addAll((Collection<?>) input.readObject());
           input.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see, I created an `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` for the 3 methods.

Is it bad idea? Should I declare and initialize only one `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream` and use it every time I need it?

I haven't run into any problem yet, but I have a doubt.

Comment: are you sure your code works ? When you call `startSendingHeartBeat()`, the thread is blocked inside an infinite loop. I do not think you can do `startSendingHeartBeat()` and `startReceivingMessage()` at same time. Or maybe this code is just for example ?

Comment: Yeah, this code is just an example, the original code is working fine. actually I'm using a `Timer` and `TimerTask` for the heartbeat method.

Comment: as long as you are not using instances of `ObjectOutputStream` at the same time, I do not see any problem. When you pass from `authenticate()` to either `startSendingHeartBeat()` or `startReceivingMessage()`, the `ObjectOutputStream` inside `authenticate()` is no longer active. Be aware that your `ObjectOutputStream`s are just a fascade over your `socket.getOutputStream()`. Same goes for your `ObjectInputStream`. Personally I would centralize all logique in one place (a method?) and use some sort of state machine to track the current state and transition between states.